# How to generate a separated dll file for the code of a specific namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll

I have an asp.net mvc application, when I compile, it creates one dll file
However, I have some code that I would like to re-use in other projects

I guess I could create another project, then put this specific code inside it and it would generate a separated dll file.

But is there another way to process in order to put the code of a specific namespace of my current project inside a separated dll file?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Put that code in a separate project--make that project a "Class Library".  This will create a DLL for that project, and you only need to add it as a reference on the original project and any other project that needs to share that code.